# Dynamically Adding Similar Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push similar objects into an array and in each object I'm pushing some values, but the values updated are reflecting in all objects. I want to add only three values from the foo array into the 1st object and other 3 in foo of second object, but in both the objects, all six values are appearing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='myCtrl'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
myapp=angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.inp=[];
   var a={foo:[]};
   var barcode='one_two_three_four_five_six';
   var arr=barcode.split('_'),k=-1;
   for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(i%3 == 0){
          $scope.inp.push(a);
          k++;}
   $scope.inp[k].foo.push(arr[i]);
   }
});
</script>
<body>
<div ng-repeat='x in inp track by $index'>{{(x)}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a temporary array variable to hold the 3 values and push that value to foo array

```
var temp=[];
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    temp[i%3]=arr[i];
    if((i+1)%3==0){
        foo.push(temp);
        temp=[];
        k++;
    }
}
```